# Given a monetary amount, calculate the equivalent change

Tags: java, beginner, change-making-problem

I have written a program that takes in some amount of money, and prints the equivalent change (starting at hundred dollars, to fifty, to twenty, down the pennies). Here is the code:

```
System.out.print("Enter amount of money: ");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

double value = scan.nextDouble();
int valueIntegral = (int) value;
int valueFractional = (int) Math.round(100 * value - 100 * valueIntegral);

// Integral values

int hundred = valueIntegral / 100;

int fifty = (valueIntegral % 100) / 50;

int twenty = ((valueIntegral % 100) % 50) / 20;

int ten = (((valueIntegral % 100) % 50) % 20) / 10;

int five = ((((valueIntegral % 100) % 50) % 20) % 10) / 5;

int one = (((((valueIntegral % 100) % 50) % 20) % 10) % 5) / 1;

// Fractional values

int quarter = valueFractional / 25;

int dime = (valueFractional % 25) / 10;

int nickel = ((valueFractional % 25) % 10) / 5;

int penny = (((valueFractional % 25) % 10) % 5) / 1;

System.out.println(hundred + " hundred dollar bills\n" +
                   fifty + " fifty dollar bills\n" +
                   twenty + " twenty dollar bills\n" +
                   ten + " ten dollar bills\n" +
                   five + " five dollar bills\n" +
                   one + " one dollar bills\n" +
                   quarter + " quarters\n" +
                   dime + " dimes\n" +
                   nickel + " nickels\n" +
                   penny + " pennies");
```

What I want to know is that without using loops or any iterative structures is this an acceptable way to accomplish this task? What would be a more elegant way? (those chains of modulo division are ugly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without loops or similar "advanced" structures, there isn't much you can do to simplify this.

You could save the duplication in extra variables. It might look like this:

```
int hundred = valueIntegral / 100;

int remainderHundred = valueIntegral % 100;
int fifty = remainderHundred / 50;

int remainderFifty = remainderHundred % 50;
int twenty = remainderFifty / 20;

int remainderTwenty = remainderFifty % 50;
int ten = remainderTwenty / 10;

[...]
```

You have to decide if it's more readable. It's certainly less complex (and mistakes/typos are easier to catch), but it might take away some clarity.

**Misc**

- you have a bit too much vertical space. Not every line needs its own paragraph.
- your comments don't add all that much value. The variable names already tell me all the comments do.